# Rename/delete files in Mac OS X save window

Tags: macos, finder, file

Is it somehow possible to rename/delete/copy files when saving a file and the Finder window pops up? I know you can do it with Windows, is it possible with Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about operating on files in the folder structure you see in the Save window as if you were working in a Finder window, the answer is no.

The only operation that approaches this is to click on a filename appearing in the Save window, which will then rename the file portion of the filename, and save the file in its native format.

Below I'm saving a TextEdit file, (Untitled.rtf is the default file name & extension):

[image: Picker]

When I click on the Word document 3D_Course_v2.Doc, the filename changes to match, but keeps the format of the file, as evident by the .rtf:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A quick test in OS X 10.10 shows that you can copy and delete, but not rename files from the save dialog box. Right(control)-clicking on a file brings up the options for Move to Trash and Duplicate. The usual behavior of changing a file name by clicking on the already-selected file does not seem to work as it does in the Finder.

[image: Save dialog]

Answer (score 1):

A commercial extension called [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) provides this. Tested against OS X 10.10.3.

It has a few other nice features, like letting you pick an open Finder window as the save/open destination.